# There was a problem while parsing this package when installing an .apk file served from PHP backend

Tags: android, download, apk

I want that if any user makes the payment then a `.apk` file is downloaded. I have done the payment part but when it comes to downloading my file download but while installing it, it shows an error -"**There was a problem while parsing this package**"
here is my PHP code-

> $file_name = '';  //File name
>
> $file_path = ''; //file path
>
> header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
>
> header("Content-length: " . filesize($file_path));
>
> header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name .
> '"');
>
> ob_end_flush();
>
> readfile($file_path);
>
> return true;

Sometimes it shows an error-**"Download Failed"** while downloading and "**There was a problem while parsing this package**" error while installing the `.apk` file. The apk file is ok and fully-functional.

Comment: The problem is with your APK file, it isn't compatible with your device. Try testing the APK directly on multiple devices.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with downloading or php. Only with installing an apk file from device. Please write a better title and post. Remove php code and post install code.

Comment: Aside from potential compatibility problems mentioned above, I'd also open the apk file in hexviewer to ensure file is not poluted with ie php notice. But as apk is zip archive, you can also check its integrity